# latest appcompat library makes menu title to capital case .what to do change it to lower case

Tags: android, menu, android-appcompat

I am using latest appcompact library in my applicaion.I have everything good but from changing my library sherlock to appcompat my menu look is changed it changed from lowercase to capital case.I have tried many solutions like changing style  text appearance of menu,making custom style for menu but i didnt got solution.Please anyone have solution give me response

Answer (score 0):

if you're using AppCompat the parent style is:

```
<style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```